# Can anyone give a brief overview of how to proceed with Named Entity Recognition in Tamil Language?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have looked at Stanford NER and Polyglot. Both does not support Tamil Language.
I would like to use ML along with some rule based NLP processing to do the entity recognition

Comment: Hi, I'm looking into a similar research area right now. Would you mind sharing whether you were able to find any libraries or what was the solution you came up with? Would be of great help!

Answer (score 1):

Neither Stanford NER nor Polyglot are rule-based. If you are only considering rule-based systems, you should probably look for existing frameworks that process Tamil correctly, or head to generic ones (e.g. [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/)).

Have a look at [this paper](http://www.cs.uccs.edu/~jkalita/papers/2011/SharmaPadmajaMachineLearning2011.pdf) that report existing NER systems for Tamil, you may contact authors.

If you find no system available, it should be rather easy to train one using existing datasets such as [NER-FIRE2013](http://au-kbc.org/nlp/NER-FIRE2013/) and [NER-FIRE2014](http://au-kbc.org/nlp/NER-FIRE2014/): ask organizers how it would be possible to obtain access to those datasets.

Hope this helps!